# How to get the smallest possible linux setup for a desktop

Tags: linux, debian, ubuntu

I'd like to setup a minimal linux installation with only the essential utilities and nothing else.
It'd be nice if a package manager comes with the distro. The distro should be under 500MB and should be easy to install. So, let's just ignore Arch, Gentoo and Debian out of this.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? You'd need more than that for a minimal working system.

Comment: Would be much easier and quicker to simply do a bare install of Debian.  You could maybe check the preseed file(s) for a Debian base install and see what debs it includes.  Just be aware that Ubuntu may require other dependencies, etc. and have different options in its preseed file(s)

Comment: @ivanivan I know bro, but being crazy at times is fun, crashing my own system is good

Comment: @bgvaughan okay, let's consider that we are trying to get the barebones system , but you are restricted to the installed distribution and cannot download anything

Comment: @IporSircer , you're the man!

Answer (score 5):

If your goal is to learn how Linux works and build it from the ground up, I would suggest reading [Linux From Scratch](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/) or getting started by [installing Gentoo](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Handbook:Main_Page).

If your goal is to have a very small or minimal Linux system I would suggest investigating the [Alpine Linux distribution](https://alpinelinux.org/).

The problem with doing what you're asking with Ubuntu is that Ubuntu has a giant wad of integrated software, so just "keeping the package manager and network manager" means you'll need to retain 1/3 of your system just so that software continues to function.  (Also you didn't clarify whether this was a graphical desktop or text console.  I'm answering on the assumption of text console, because keeping the desktop graphics means you'll need another 1/3 of the usual things installed).

To elaborate on the projects above, "Linux from Scratch" teaches you all about kernel, user-land, drivers, device nodes and all that stuff at the deepest levels of a Linux system, and you can build a working system out of a bare essential list of pieces.

The Gentoo project is a distribution aimed at building "live from source" linux systems where you get to fully configure every piece of software you bring into the system.  They have a very nice thorough document to walk you through the process of installing everything, and it will teach you tons of things about how different software projects interact to produce a full Linux system.  I should maybe say that it will *force* you to learn all these things in order to get a working system :-)   It also takes a very long time to compile everything from source, so only go this route if you are patient and very interested in learning.

Alpine is sort of the end product of the two above.  It is a package-based Linux distro where they basically started with the Linux From Scratch principles, then compiled a large collection of software with minimal options (as you might do with Gentoo) and then provide these packages for you to download with a package manager.  Alpine results in very small very simple systems, but you can get running with it much quicker than Gentoo.

Ubuntu is the opposite end of the spectrum.  Ubuntu enables every option in every package so that you have all the features at your fingertips.  But, it also results in an extremely complicated and highly integrated system, so you can't easily pick it apart.  If you attack a fully installed Ubuntu system with the "apt purge" command you will just eventually break your system without having learned much.

Hope that helps.  And yes, people are downvoting you because your question sounds silly ;-)

Comment: I don't mind the downvotes, and yeah, barebones is the end product I need and I've gone through LFS and Gentoo, and Gentoo was my previous installation, and LFS takes time to build so I was trying to find a way to reach the minimal stage of CLI and essentials without having to download a new ISO for Arch or Debian Netinst, and just cut down everything to a point where I could start building stuff up again, thanks for the answer.
And yes, I apologise for having to make you type so much

Comment: Also, I like the Alpine Linux, which version of Alpine (Standard, Xen..etc) would you recommend , if I said I wanted to install it over wifi and not LAN

Comment: Depends what your goal is, but I'd say Standard.  I've actually never installed it on bare metal, just containers within another system.  I don't think lan vs. wifi will matter since all the packages are small.

Comment: Oh, and I should mention [Damn Small Linux](http://www.damnsmalllinux.org/) though I haven't used them in a long while.

Comment: Used DSL, it's a little uncomfortable. And Alpine is also a long process as a lot of stuff needs to be done manually, guess I'll just work on creating a distro for myself. Thanks anyways.